# Is $f = X^p - p^2$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $p \geq 3$ a prime number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Is $f = X^p - p^2$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $p \geq 3$ a prime number? Normally I would use Eisenstein, but that does not work in this case. I tried calculating $f(X+1)$ but that does not seem to give any progress. For the context, I am trying to determine the splitting field $\Omega_f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the degree of this extension. I am guessing it should be $\Omega_f = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{p^2},\zeta_p)$, with degree $p(p-1)$, but I'm stuck in the proof. Can someone confirm that this is the case?

In the case $f = X^p - p$, I have done the following. In $\mathbb{C}$ we see that the roots of $f$ are given by $\zeta_p^k \sqrt[p]{p}$ with $0 \leq k \leq p-1$. Now we look at the tower
$$
\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{p}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{p},\zeta_p) = \Omega_{f}. 
$$
The first has degree $p$ with minimum polynomial $X^p - p$ (irreducible, Eisenstein for $p$). The second has minimum polynomial $\Phi_p$ of grade $p-1$. We see that this is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{p}) \subset \mathbb{R}$, since $\zeta_p \in \mathbb{C}$, and also all powers $\zeta_p^k \notin \mathbb{R}$ for $1 \leq k \leq p-1$. So the total grade is $p(p-1) = p^2 - p$. Is this correct?

Comment: It is not true that if a polynomial has no roots in a field $K$ then it is irreducible over $K$, which you seem to claim for $\Phi_p$. For example, the polynomial $X^4+3X^2+2$ has no real roots, but is reducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. The usual argument to show that $\Phi_p$ is irreducible is to note that $\Phi_p(X+1)$ is Eisenstein at $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A root of $X^p-p^2=0$ generates the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[p]p)$ which has degree $p$ over $\Bbb Q$ (using Eisenstein).

Comment: This answer is correct, however I think that your first statement is not obvious.

Comment: @Angina, could you please elaborate on the first statement?

Comment: Since $p$ is odd, it follows that $(p^{2/p})^{(p+1)/2} = p \cdot p^{1/p}$. So in fact it doesn't matter all that much that it says $p^2$ instead of $p$